# Executing local (--save-dev) tools by npm

Tags: node.js, npm, bower

I just installed bower via `npm install bower --save-dev` because I want to have this available for everybody who checks the branch out and runs "npm update". I knew how to execute bower if I installed it with `npm install bower -g` but how do I actually execute it now?

this way does not satisfy me:

```
./node_modules/bower/bin/bower -v
```

Isn't there something like `npm tools bower -v`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no npm tools command. But here is an [alternative solution](http://www.2ality.com/2016/01/locally-installed-npm-executables.html).

If your shell is `bash`, you can add function into your .bashrc.

```
# ~/.bashrc
function npm-tools {                                                                                                  
    (PATH=$(npm bin):$PATH; eval $@;)                                                                              
}
```

Then you can run command like following to achieve what you want.

```
# $ tree node_modules/ -L=1
# node_modules/
# └── bower
$ ./node_modules/bower/bin/bower -v
1.7.9
$ npm-tools bower -v
1.7.9
```

Comment: I did it slightly different but your tip was great!